# v-on not working with v-for which is created dynamically

Tags: vue.js, dynamic

I am looping a bit complex data using v-for. I have a text box to add new data set to it. Each cell in the table toggles to edit mode on double clicking it. It works fine when there are no new entries added. But when I add a new entry using 'Add a category' textbox, the double click is not working properly. Here is jsfiddle. Can someone help on this?

https://jsfiddle.net/9b7ckjrt/1/

```
<div id="app">
  <greeting></greeting>
</div>

<template id="example">
  <div class="hello">
    <div>
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td v-for="month in 3" :key="month">{{ month }} / {{ selectedYear }}</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody v-for="(subCategories, category) in expectedMonthlyBudget" :key="category">
          <tr v-for="(yearExpenses, subCategory, idx) in subCategories" :key="subCategory">
            <td :rowspan="Object.keys(subCategories).length + 1" v-if="idx == 0">
              {{ category }}
            </td>

            <td>
              {{ subCategory }}
            </td>

            <td v-for="month in 3" :key="month" @dblclick="toggleEditingMoney(yearExpenses[selectedYear][month])">
              <div v-if="!yearExpenses[selectedYear][month].editing">
                {{ yearExpenses[selectedYear][month].value }}
              </div>
              <div v-if="yearExpenses[selectedYear][month].editing">
                <input @keyup.esc="cancelEditingMoney(yearExpenses[selectedYear][month])" @keyup.enter="doneEditingMoney(yearExpenses[selectedYear][month])" @blur="doneEditingMoney(yearExpenses[selectedYear][month])" v-focus type="text" v-model="yearExpenses[selectedYear][month].value" />
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Add a category..." @keyup.enter="addSubCategory(category)" @keyup.esc="cancelAddingSubCategory(category)" v-model="newCategory[category]" />
            </td>
            <td v-for="month in 3" :key="month"></td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: '#example',
  directives: {
    focus: {
      // directive definition
      inserted: function (el) {
        el.focus()
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleEditingMoney: function(element) {
      this.beforeEditingCache = element.value;
      element.editing = true;
    },
    doneEditingMoney: function(element) {
      if(element.value.toString().trim() == '') { element.value = 0; }
      if(isNaN(element.value)) { element.error = true; }
      else { element.error = false; }

      element.editing = false;
    },
    cancelEditingMoney: function(element) {
      element.value = this.beforeEditingCache;
      element.editing = false;
    },
    cancelAddingSubCategory: function(category) {
      this.newCategory[category] = '';
    },
    addSubCategory: function(category) {
      for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
        this.expectedMonthlyBudget[category][this.newCategory[category]] = {
            "2020": {
              "1": {
                "value": 0
              },
              "2": {
                "value": 0
              },
              "3": {
                "value": 0
              }
            }
          };
      }

      this.newCategory[category] = '';
    },
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      selectedYear: 2020,
      cachedMoney: 0,
      newCategory: {
        "Income": '',
        "Expense": '',
        "EMI": '',
        "EquityInvestment": '',
        "DebtInvestment": ''
      },

      beforeEditingCache: 0,
      expectedMonthlyBudget: {
        "Income": {
          "Salary": {
            "2020": {
              "1": {
                "value": 1231312,
                "editing": false
              },
              "2": {
                "value": 324,
                "editing": false
              },
              "3": {
                "value": 324324,
                "editing": false
              }
            }
          },
          "Illegal": {
            "2020": {
              "1": {
                "value": 1231312,
                "editing": false
              },
              "2": {
                "value": 324,
                "editing": false
              },
              "3": {
                "value": 324324,
                "editing": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "Expense": {
          "Rent": {
            "2020": {
              "1": {
                "value": 1231312,
                "editing": false
              },
              "2": {
                "value": 324,
                "editing": false
              },
              "3": {
                "value": 324324,
                "editing": false
              }
            }
          },
          "Car": {
            "2020": {
              "1": {
                "value": 1231312,
                "editing": false
              },
              "2": {
                "value": 324,
                "editing": false
              },
              "3": {
                "value": 324324,
                "editing": false
              }
            }
          },
          "Bike": {
            "2020": {
              "1": {
                "value": 1231312,
                "editing": false
              },
              "2": {
                "value": 324,
                "editing": false
              },
              "3": {
                "value": 324324,
                "editing": false
              }
            }
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding properties to an object you run into what Vue's docs call [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

In relation to your code what this means is that this part

```js
    addSubCategory: function(category) {
      for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
        this.expectedMonthlyBudget[category][this.newCategory[category]] = {
```

won't add the new object to Vue's change detection flow.

You have to use `Vue.set` (or its alias, `this.$set`):

```js
    addSubCategory: function(category) {
      for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
        this.$set(this.expectedMonthlyBudget[category], this.newCategory[category], {
            "2020": {
              "1": {
                "value": 0,
                "editing": false
              },
              "2": {
                "value": 0,
                "editing": false
              },
              "3": {
                "value": 0,
                "editing": false
              }
            }
          });
      }

      this.newCategory[category] = '';
    },
```

Note that I've also initialized the "editing" property (instead of creating it inside `toggleEditingMoney` method via `element.editing = true;`), as this is also necessary so Vue is aware of its presence.

[image: Edit aged-moon-jcjn8]

Comment: @Sandeep if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark button next to it :)